Engine to solve direct mates on larger boards?
Does anyone know of a problem engine that will solve direct mates on larger boards (e.g. 10x10, 12x12 etc), please?

In response to my query, someone offline has suggested WinChloe by Christian Poisson, and that seems to be working well for 10x10 & 12x12. See WinChloe website here.
I'm told it can scale up to 256x256, which is boggling large. It isn't free, but in my opinion having used it for other features for many years, it's well worth the money.
I don't know any other tool that offers this capability.
